# What are the icons used in the Study Room website?

Tags: website-design, icon

I want to understand how the icons used in Study room' whiteboard were inserted.

To see what I mean, [navigate to the site](http://www.getstudyroom.com/demo#), click Create button and then Join button on the animation.  If you observe closely the tip of the brush, pen etc changes based on the color selected:

[image]

From the google developer kit, I don't see any background picture at the place of icon but can see some junk character. Can anyone throw some light on what type of icons are used and how to design those?

Comment: Don't ask users to jump through hoops. You should put as much effort into your question as others will into their answer. Take a screen shot and link to that in your question. It's also **very** difficult to understand what you are asking here.

Comment: @Scott just updated

Comment: I agree..  what is your question?  Are you wanting to know how to make icons or are you trying to figure out how to design something similar to the developer kit?

Comment: @Matt_2.0 obviously, want to find out how to make those type of icons

Comment: They're icon fonts, is that what you're trying to figure out?

Comment: Yes, does it work in all types browsers or HTML5 supported ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go it [iconmoon](http://icomoon.io/), you can follow their tutorial and get yourself whatever icons you want. The junk character is a character using iconmoon font. if you look at the rule `.icon-font{}` in dev tools (on your screenshot) you'll see `font-family: 'iconmoon';` This way you can control the behavior of that div a little easier with just css and text, no images are involved.

It will work in just about all browsers, (ie7,8,9,10, ff, chrome), and you can base64 encode it as well (if you want just a couple characters) and drop into the style sheet.

Comment: I would be good if you could add more information, like a tutorial, instead of just linking to an external site (if the link goes down this answer becomes useless in the future and posting "tutorials" and "external links" we try to deviate from as much as possible).

Comment: In this case if icomoon goes down the tutorial will be useless as the tutorial is for icomoon which is an online application. This is a great application for quickly creating icon fonts using either their icons or your own.